# jQuery - get actual position of displayed text inside a text-align:center link?

Tags: jquery

I have a horizontal menu of links that are styled with fixed width, display:block and centered text.  So, while the link (block) itself may be 200px wide, the actual displayed text may start 25 or 30 px from the left edge, depending on the length of the word in the link. The backgrounds are transparent.

I want to create a new div and line it up with the link that is clicked, NOT with the left edge of the block (which is invisible), but with the left position of the TEXT inside the block.

Is there any way to select the position of the centered text inside the link?  Since it's a part of the "a" element itself, children() doesn't seem to help...

Answer (score 2):

Put your text in a span container and find its position

```
var tpos = $('#one span').position();

$('#two').css({
    'left': tpos.left
});
```

[sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/ufS4g/3/)